# Appending array values to different containers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append array values in their respective div's, I've the following array of values with their "THINGS" taht points to the respective div's named as `THING1`, `THING2` and so on

```
["THING1", "ABC", "123", "THING2", "DEF", "456", "GHI", "789", "JKL", "123", "THING3", "MNO", "123", "PQR", "546"]
```

I'm checking the id's as follow

```
if(this.getAttribute('id')=="ITEM"+i)
{
//exits
}
```

All I need is to append the values after the indicators (THING) in their respective div's (ITEM).

**My Attempt:**
JS:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= myThings.length; i++) {
                var item;
                if (myThings[i] != null)
                   item = "ITEM1";
                else    if (myThings[i][i] != null)
                     item = "ITEM2";
                else       if (myThings[i][i] != null)
                    item= "ITEM3";
                else           if (myThings[i][i] != null)
                     item = "ITEM4";

                    if (myThings[i] == item)
                    {
var e = myThings[i];
                       $('#'+j).after(e); 
                    }
                };
```

HTML:

```
<div id="ITEM1"></div>
<div id="ITEM2"></div>
<div id="ITEM3"></div>
<div id="ITEM4"></div>
```

Comment: Can you also post your html?

Comment: YES, i'm updating my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `after()` or test if its there jQuery won't append if it can't find it.

Here is my approach:

```js
var myThings = ["THING1", "ABC", "123", "THING2", "DEF", "456", "GHI", "789", "JKL", "123", "THING3", "MNO", "123", "PQR", "546"];
var divs = "ITEM",
    indicator = "THING",
    t = 0;
    j = 0;
$.each(myThings, function(i,v){ 
  if (v.indexOf(indicator) !== -1) {
     t = v.replace(indicator, ""); 
     j = 1;
  } else {
     $('#'+divs+t).append($('<span />').attr('id', indicator + t + "_" + j).text(v));
     j++;
  }
});
```

```css
span {
   margin-right:15px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ITEM1"></div>
<div id="ITEM2"></div>
<div id="ITEM3"></div>
```

Comment: Why THING2 is  displaying? I dont need that.

Comment: THING1 is also not needed dear. Just THINGS are to tell on which ITEMS it is needed to append

Comment: Better now? is that what you mean?

Comment: YES, clean and fine solution. +1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74778/discussion-between-developer-and-shlomi-hassid).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can loop through the items using the i variable and add them after the div:

```
var myThings = ["THING1", "ABC", "123", "THING2", "DEF", "456", "GHI", "789", "JKL", "123", "THING3", "MNO", "123", "PQR", "546"];


var divs = $("div[id^='ITEM']"); //this selects all divs that have an id starting with "ITEM"

for (var i = 0; i <= myThings.length; i++) {
var item = $(divs[i]); //this selects the current item
    item.after("<p>" + myThings[i] + "</p>"); //this adds a paragraph after the item

                    }
```

This will add the first item after the end of the first div, the second item after the end of the second div, etc.

Also, you need an html element to send to the after() function, not just a text string. In the example, I've wrapped it in a paragraph tag to do this.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v5juxf6q/)

Also, I'm not sure if you want to use after() (add the item after the end of the div) or append() (add the item inside the div). You can just change .after( to .append( if you want append.

Comment: Not appending all things in demo.

Comment: Also, each thing should have the name and code in same paragraph. Like, Thing=> ABC 123 etc